# Write Plugin for Android App

Tags: android

i'll try to develop an app which is enabled for plugins like in windows-.Net-world DLLs.

i will have small rectangle-linearlayouts in my app where the user is able to manage them with visible on/off. later on i or someone else will give the user a new plugin, which the apps is displaying now.

is it possible? if yes: how?
are there good sites out there you could direct me?

regards
fly

Comment: There are better question/answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239596/plugins-architecture-for-an-android-app

Answer (score 27):

It is possible to have a plugin architecture for your application.  These links should help you out:

- http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2010/06/plugins.html
- http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2011/01/plugins-with-user-interface.html